# Копирование в буфер нужной колонки в DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Как реализовать копирование нужных колонок из таблицы? Например при клике на кнопку в буфер должны упасть все значения, которые были в первом и третьем столбце.

PS Копирование всей таблицы происходит таким способом

```
dgvReports.SelectAll();
DataObject dataObject = dgvReports.GetClipboardContent();
if (dataObject != null)
   Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject);
```

Comment: А куда потом вставлять будете?

Comment: Да без разницы.. Текстовый редактор, excel и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Сделать это возможно
Но необходимо немного манипуляций.
Во первых, отключить сортировку у столбцов, чтобы их можно было выделять
Программно:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

Или через UI
[image: Изменение в конструкторе]

А уже после этого можно добавить код выделения столбцов:

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Selected = true;
DataObject dobj = dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent();
if (dobj != null)
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(dobj);
```